# How to create a list of terms who's posts also have a predefined external term?

Tags: filters, wpdb, multi-taxonomy-query, terms

I have a pretty extensive music collection and my friends are always borrowing my stuff. I would like to keep better track of my library so I'm building a sudo-checkout system using WP.

The collection was already in WP using terms to sort everything. The main taxonomies are *artist*, *year released*, *label*, and *genre*. I want to add a new taxonomy called *whereisit*. The post type used is called *album*.

Because of the way that other plugins interact with the site (I'm a music geek) I can't easily use post meta for inventory status term. If it matters at the moment I'm using Scribu's plugin to autogenerate taxonomy search fields.

> *The question:*
>
> How can I display a list of terms who's related posts also match another fixed term?

For example: Show a list of terms for *artists* who's *whereisit* term is *ihaveit*. If all of the artist's albums have an *whereisit* term of *idonthaveit*, do not display the *artist* term in the list.

Or more simply: If all of my albums by a particular artist are loaned out to someone else, don't display the artist's name in the Artist list.

Would something like this have to be done through wpdb? Filtering a loop is easy enough, but translating that to a list is over my head.  :)

**Edit:**
I replaced the terms *inhouse* with *ihaveit*, *checkedout* with *idonthaveit*, and the taxonomy named *inventorystatus* with *whereisit* for better clarity.

Comment: you lost me at "If the term inhouse is checkedout"

Comment: @Bainternet I simplified the term names, hopefully this easier to follow now.  :)

Comment: So you want a list of albums by artist that are ihaveit?

Comment: @bainternet yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly you want to get a list of `albums` (posts) of a specific artist(taxonomy) and that are have `ihaveit` term.

if so the its a simple query using `tax_query`:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, //get all
    'post_type' => 'album', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'artist',
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array( 'artist-slug' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'whereisit',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('ihaveit')
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while($query->have_posts())
{
    $query->the_post();
    //to your thing / loop here
}
```

Comment: You phrased what I am trying to accomplish correctly but were are taking different meaning from it. My hope with this ticket is to create a list of taxonomies in a select menu that could then be searched. Related WP functions might be for example (to display all taxonomy terms), use `the_terms`, `get_the_term_list`, or `wp_list_categories`.